# Find $18(a+b+c)$ given that $a,b,c$ satisfying certain equation

Tags: polynomials

> If the real number $a,b,c$ satisfy the equation
>   $$\frac{3x^3-2x^2+x+1}{3x^3-2x^2-x-1}=\frac{3x^3-2x^2+5x-13}{3x^3-2x^2-5x+13}$$ then find the value of $18(a+b+c)$.

I got a solution as $7÷2$ as letting $3x^3-2x^2=m$ and $x+1=n$ and $5x-13=l$ and by applying componento and dividendo we get $n= l$ which gives $x=7÷2$ but I don't know the other solutions.Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You have approached this the right way, but you neglected one possibility.

Multiplying out by the denominators, your equation becomes $$m^2+(n-l)m-ln=m^2-(n-l)m-ln$$
This gives you **either** $n-l=0$ (which you have found) **or** $m=0$.

Do remember, when you find $x$ and substitute it back into the original equation, to check that neither of the denominators becomes zero.